# Unpivot column pyspark dataframe where value is list of dictionary

Tags: json, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a pandas dataframe from list of dictionaries and used json_normalize to unpivot one column. Now I have to convert the code to use pyspark instead of pandas.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(list_json,'Messages',['ID'])

ID, Active, Description, Priority
21122, true ,Test description1, 2
21233,true ,Test description1, 2
21233,true ,test2 , 3
```

In Pyspark, I couldn't figure a similar function.

I have created a dataframe using below code. But don't know how to get it unpivoted as above.

```
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(list_json_messages_tea).map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
df = spark.read.json(df)

ID, Messages
21122, [{"Active": "true", "Description": "Test description1", "Priority": "2"}]
21233, [{"Active": "true", "Description": "Test description1", "Priority": "2"}, {"Active": "true", "Description": "test2",  "Priority": "3"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the equivalent is to use `inline(from_json())`:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr('ID', "inline(from_json(Messages, 'array<struct<Active:string,Description:string,Priority:string>>'))")

df2.show()
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+
|   ID|Active|      Description|Priority|
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+
|21122|  true|Test description1|       2|
|21233|  true|Test description1|       2|
|21233|  true|            test2|       3|
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+
```